# Can a hashed password by MD5 be replaced by SHA-256 password?

Tags: php, security, hash, md5, sha

I have to change a project password migration and I'd like to knwo if it's possible to change the hash method to a hashed password.

I'm thinking that is possible, but Idon't if I have to decrypt (which it isn't possible) or I can apply SHA-256 to a MD5 hashed password.

I'll appreciate any advice or help.
Thanks!

Comment: Do neither, Please dont __roll your own__ password hashing, specially not using `MD5()` or `SHA1()`.  PHP provides [`password_hash()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php)
and [`password_verify()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) please use them for the safety of your users.

Comment: You will have to make the change as part of the user login. When they next login, do your current password checking, if it passes, you have the plain text password validated. Then put that through the new hashing process and flag the user as moved to the new mechanism so that you will use `password_verisy()` next time they login

Comment: I have checked this methods. Thanks. But this is a old project. Do you recommend keep MD5 here?

Comment: NO, MD5 is not a safe mechanism. What version of PHP are you using in this project

Comment: It's... hard to explain. It's a macro-project, divided in smaller projects, one of them was coded in vanilla PHP 5.5.38 and a Symfony project with PHP 7.4.2

Comment: SHA256 is equally incorrect. You're replacing one wrong thing with another wrong thing. You need to use `password_hash`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like [RiggsFolly](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2310830/riggsfolly) already mentioned in the comments you should use the `password_hash()` and the `password_verify()` function instead of some MD5 or SHA1 Implementations since sha1 and md5 are both no secure hashing functions for passwords, they should only be used for checksums.

[How to use bcrypt for hashing in php](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-use-bcrypt-for-hashing-passwords-in-php/)

if the `password_hash` function is not in your php version or outdated then you can look [for a secure implementation for this problem](https://github.com/PHPAuth/PHPAuth) which is not a single man algorithm and exists for longer.